# Java script adding option values

Tags: javascript

Im trying to add selected option but it doesnt seem to work.I want to be able to add selected options and display them in a text box with id = tot. At the moment it does view the value in the text box but it does not add it just views the value of the option i have selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function check_sm() {
        var value1 = 0;
        var sm1 = document.getElementById("slides");
        for (var i = 0; i < sm1.length; i++) {
            if (sm1[i].selected)
            { value1 = (eval(value1) + eval(sm1[i].value)); }
        } document.getElementById("SCregistration").tot.value = value1;

    }

</script>





<body>
<form>
Do you want a copy of the short course details?
<select id="slides" onChange="check_sm()">
    <option value="50">Yes</option>
    <option value="20">No</option>
</select>

</body>
</form>
```

Comment: What the heck are you using `eval()` here for?  It has no place here whatsoever.  `value1 += parseInt(sm1.value, 10);`.

Comment: Also, `getElementById` only returns *one* element, not a list of elements.

Comment: In the first line of your function , isn't `var value1 = 0;` supposed to be `var value1 = document.getElementById("SCregistration").tot.value` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function check_sm() {
    var slides = document.getElementById("slides");
    var selected = slides.selectedIndex;
    var optValue = parseInt(slides.options[selected].value, 10);
    var oldTot = parseInt(document.getElementById('SCregistration').tot.value, 10);
    document.getElementById('SCregistration').tot.value = oldTot + optValue;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7B3Uq/6/)

Comment: It doesnt seem like its working ... is there anything i should know?

Comment: I fixed several typos. Also, it should be `slides.options`, not `slides.childNodes`.

Comment: I checked out your demo and it works however its not working in my script i dont get whats wron... grrrr so frustrating!